# Can't Upload SSL Self-Signed Certificate Files to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I'm following this guide to deploy to Heroku: https://gist.github.com/harlantwood/3792692

I've created the files required (site.key, site.csr, final.crt). When I run **heroku domains:add myapp.herokuapp.com** the response is 'myapp.herokuapp.com is currently in use by another app'.

What does that mean and how can I stop whatever app is using it?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring that step?